# Connector identification; how to case mount

Tags: connector, identification, panel-mounting

I have these connectors and need to case-mount the female part of the pair. I've been trying to find out their mfg/part no so that I can look at the spec to figure out how to mount it.m, but no luck.

The drawing below is my best attempt to show the identifying mark that is on the male connector. The pictures are of the connector set. Supposedly the female connector will case-mount, but having looked at if for a few hours, I am stumped.  If anyone has an example to share, that would be a wonderful thing.

[image: Connectors]

[image: Drawing of mark]

[More photos](https://photos.app.goo.gl/E8pHodxKcFgaFI3l2)

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on a style of panel mount commonly used for switches. It snaps into a rectangular hole.

[image: Picture of panel mount part of connector pair]

- Note the flange on the left end. One dimension of the hole should be just large enough to fit the connector body and then stop against the flange. (Prettier versions of this style have a flange that goes around all four sides.)
- The other dimension of the hole should be wide enough that the wings can be squeezed to fit past it. The ridges on the wings will then press against the hole edges and prevent the connector from coming out of the hole, and can do this for a variety of panel thicknesses. (Make sure that your rectangular hole has a crisp edge on the inside for best grip.)

I recommend making sure you are prepared to cut a rectangular hole with neat, straight, intentionally dimensioned edges. Use a file and test fitting to get it to final size so that you don't accidentally remove too much.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful response.  I think I now see how to cut the hole, though the "wings" part is a bit of a mystery, but I'll figure it out.  Very much appreciate your taking the time and effort to respond.

Answer (score 1):

These are JST SM connectors which can be used for (not very pretty) panel mounting. A drawing of the hole to be punched is in the datasheet:

https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSM.pdf

For the 2 wire connector the main dimensions are a rectangular hole of 5.15 x 9.6 mm.